# Where to place controller hepler methods to keep harmony with design patterns while building .NET Core Api?

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller

i am new to building API's, and right now i'm trying to build my first application. I would like to keep architecture of my application compliant with the design patterns as much as possible. I have a service layer, services are injected to the controllers, and are responsible for communication with the repositories. I would like to split some of my logic located in controllers to make my code more clean.
As an example i have a controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UsersController(IUserService userService) : base()
    {

        this._userService = userService;

    }

    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateUserAsync(AuthenticationDTO authentication)
    {

        var user = await _userService.AuthenticateUserAsync(authentication.Username, authentication.Password);

        var tokenString = .....

    }

...

}
```

I would like to create a method responsible for generating authentication token. Where do i have to locate such a logic? Should i place it in UserService, or maybe write in in UsersController class? Can i write private methods in controller classes, or maybe Controllers should only contain methods exposed through an api interface?

Comment: It's totally okay to write it in the controller, but when your controller become huge, things will start to be nasty. What I would do is to create a Helper folder where I put all Code that is relevant to some service, but not a service itself.

Answer (score 1):

#### Rest-Api - Think in resources.

This question is all about the way you think about your rest-api (if you are building one). There are differences between rest apis, web apis and SOAP, but I'll assume that you are building a rest-api.

In case of a generic web api, you'll have to decide the way to break down your application into multiple controllers.

[Check Microsoft Rest-Api guide.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design) The most important section out of this is:

> Organize the API around resources

So in your example, let's assume that your resource is the user session. Then you can have a `UserController` with the appropriate verbs, where you can Create (POST) Update (PUT/PATCH) Delete (DELETE) or retrieve (GET) the `User` resource.

Now you need a session, don't you? Or a Token. Easy:

`TokenController` and the action is of course (POST) - Create token with username and password

`SessionController` - Create a token.

This way you will minimize the actions. As an extra, if the `User` has `Accounts`, then create a new controller called `UserAccountsController` that will be server by a rest url like `users/1/accounts GET`

#### Services layer

Having a services layer where you have all your business logic is the way to go. Keeping in mind the SRP (single responsibility principle), the one and only responsibility of the Controller, is to control the code flow for the Http response creation and coordinate the actions to do so.

The actual business logic should be implemented in a service layer. This way, you'll have controllers that even with multiple actions will be quite minimal (4/5 rows per action).

#### User inheritance

Common logic between the controllers can be achieved by using a `MyApiController: ControllerBase` that contains reusable code.

DON'T use Helper classes. It's an antipattern. [Utility classes are evil](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html#utility-classes-are-evil) is an excellent article on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just place that kind of helper classes or methods into some folder called Infrastructure for example. 
For this example, just create interface ITokenGenerator with Generate() method, create it's implementation class  TokenGenerator and simply inject it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the compiler allows you to write private method in controller. It just like a normal class. However, you should put everything on service, so you de-couple the logic from controller. (For example, later, you can easily migrate your logic to different UI such as MVC instead of web API)

In your example, the token generating should not be in controller or userService. I think the best is to have TokenGenerator service.